# Data not binding to table using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, binding, dotnetnuke

I am working on my first custom-built KO implementation and I had the data binding to the table in my page, but not it's not binding to it.  I can verify that my web service is getting called and it's returning data. However, I don't know why the data isn't loading into the table since I am not getting any errors.

I am sure I am missing something simple since I am a newb to this. :)

I am using KO 3.1.0.

PAGE MARKUP

```
<table class="dnnGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr class="dnnGridHeader">
            <th>Task ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date Updated</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: tasks">
        <tr class="dnnGridRow">
            <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: LastUpdatedDate"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

PAGE SCRIPT

```
var sf = $.ServicesFramework(<%=ModuleId %>);
var userId = <%=UserId%>;
var serviceUrl = sf.getServiceRoot('POC');
var moduleId = sf.getModuleId();

$(document).ready(function() {

    ko.applyBindings(TaskViewModel);

    GetTasks();

    $('#lnkSave').click(function() {
        SaveTask();
        GetTasks();
    });
});
```

IMPORTED SCRIPT

```
var Task = function(data) {

data = data || {};

var self = this;

self.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
self.ModuleId = ko.observable(data.ModelId);
self.ContentItemId = ko.observable(data.ContentItemId);
self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
self.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
self.LastUpdatedDate = ko.observable(data.LastUpdatedDate);
self.LastUpdatedBy = ko.observable(data.LastUpdatedBy);
}
var TaskViewModel = function(items) {
var self = this;

var newTask = {
    'ID': ko.observable(),
    'ModuleId': ko.observable(),
    'ContentItemId': ko.observable(),
    'Name': ko.observable(),
    'Description': ko.observable(),
    'LastUpdatedDate': ko.observable(),
    'LastUpdatedBy': ko.observable()
};
self.tasks = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function (data) {
    return new Task(data);
}));

self.updateTask = function (task) {
    GetTasks();
}
}
function SaveTask() {
var task = {
    'ModuleId': moduleId,
    'LastUpdatedBy': userId,
    'Name': $('#txtName').val(),
    'Description': $('#txtDescription').val()
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: serviceUrl + 'Task/CreateTask',
    data: JSON.stringify(task),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
    success: function (data) {
        var results = $.parseJSON(data);
        ParseResults(results, viewModel);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("STATUS: " + xhr.status + "\nERROR:\n" + thrownError);
    }
});
}
function GetTasks() {
if (TaskViewModel) {
    if (TaskViewModel.tasks) {
        TaskViewModel.tasks.removeAll();
    }
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: serviceUrl + 'Task/GetTasks?ModuleId=' + moduleId,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
    success: function (data) {
        var results = $.parseJSON(data);
        TaskViewModel.tasks = results;
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("STATUS: " + xhr.status + "\nERROR:\n" + thrownError);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the problem [to the absolute minimum](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Drop all the Ajax, make it an array of single values, remove everything that is not necessary in the strictest sense. If it still does not work after that, come back and post your reduced code.

Comment: The absolute minimum code did work originally. However, I don't want to write the application using the absolutely minimum over and over again. The application would be written in horrible spaghetti code.

Comment: You misunderstand. Your task is to single out the problem and reproduce it in as few lines of code as possible so that we don't have to debug your *entire* code. Read the link in my previous comment again.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving this line `ko.applyBindings(TaskViewModel)` to bottom of `.ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    GetTasks();

    $('#lnkSave').click(function() {
        SaveTask();
        GetTasks();
    });
    ko.applyBindings(TaskViewModel);
});
```

After this line,     `var results = $.parseJSON(data);` add a debugger; statement and open chrome developer tools (F12 key), refresh the page and step through the code using F10 key.

At this point you should be able to see the parsed data in `results`. If it is not in required format, you may need to assign TaskViewModel.tasks like this

```
TaskViewModel.tasks = ko.utils.arrayMap(results, function (task) {
                return new Task(task);
            });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to have made any difference.  Sorry.  :(